# WebView cannot scroll from top to bottom of the webpage

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, webview

I have loaded a webpage to xcode WebView. But only the upper portion of the page is loaded. I can not scroll down to the bottom of the page. Same fact for pdf. Only upper 2 pages can be scrolled. What can i do ?Here is my code. 
Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var URL = NSURL(string: "http://www.archetapp.com")
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))

  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

//for pdf

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var webViews: UIWebView!

  var path = ""

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    path  = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ibook", ofType: "pdf")!
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
    webViews.scalesPageToFit = true
    webViews.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    webViews.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.webViews.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!))        
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

  }

}
```

Comment: What is the webView frame you have given... try to increase the height of the webview and see if there is difference in scroll part?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue just today and at least in my case it was caused by having the "Scale Pages to Fit" option checked in the WebView properties. I'm assuming Carlos' reply regarding the zoom scale fixes it anyways but I didn't need the option enabled in the first place so that was my easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView : UIWebView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       //load initial
       path  = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ibook", ofType: "pdf")!
       let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
       var req = NSURLRequest(URL : url)
       webView.delegate = self // <---
       webView.loadRequest(req)
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
       //UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
       println("webViewDidStartLoad")
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
        //UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
       webViews.scalesPageToFit = true
       webViews.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
       webViews.userInteractionEnabled = true
        println("webViewDidFinishLoad")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But it's not working. I can scroll only one page. Is there any other solution?

Comment: try add in webViewDidFinishLoad -->   // webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 20; //
    webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1;